# Custom taxonomy- only output relevant terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type called 'products' the CPT has two custom taxonomies (both hierarchical); 1) 'product_type' and 2) 'product_provider'.

Each product will have both a 'product_type' and a 'product_provider' linked to it. On the archive page for each 'product_type' term I am outputting a filterable list of 'products', one of the filter options is by Provider which (obviously) filters based on the 'product_provider' custom tax.

The problem I have is outputting just the 'product_provider' terms that apply to the specific 'product_type'.

**EXAMPLE**

Product A. Product_type = 1, product_provider = W

Product B. Product_type = 1, product_provider = X

Product C. Product_type = 2, product_provider = Y

Product C. Product_type = 2, product_provider = W

On the archive page for 'product_type 1' using:

```
$terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_provider') );
```

Will output **all** terms within the 'product_provider' taxonomy - W, X, Y. I need to just output W and X - that is the 2 terms within 'product_provider' that apply to 'products' in the product_type custom tax.

I'm not sure if the answer is; a more robust term query, restructuring the CPT/taxonomies to remove the 'product_provider' - just make each provider a sub category of the specific 'product_type' (although this would lead to duplicating some providers as they offer products in multiple product_type's).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another argument in the array of argument, you have many choice to filter the results.

You can add `exclude`, `include` with an array or comma separated of the terms you want to display.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_provider',
            'include'=> array('X', 'Y')
);
```

But, if the results depends on the product_type, you'll maybe need to use `meta_key` and `meta_value` (of the product).

Of course you can mix, all these arguments if need.

If you want to get the term that belong to a product, you need to use `wp_get_object_terms()`.

You will find all details [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and [wp_get_object_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Hope it helps.